# Property 'subtle' does not exist on type 'typeof webcrypto'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm using Node v17.4 and want to consume the webcrypto API. Based on [this example](https://nodejs.org/api/webcrypto.html#rsa-key-pairs) I'm trying to import `subtle` into my project but TypeScript comes up with the error

> Property 'subtle' does not exist on type 'typeof webcrypto'.

The only thing the namespace `webcrypto` offers is [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f2dd39509ea0623ebef0f6b5f03216a1b7aa949a/types/node/v16/crypto.d.ts#L3301-L3303).

```
import crypto from 'crypto';
const { subtle } = crypto.webcrypto; // subtle doesn't exist
```

How do I get access to `subtle` ?

Answer (score 7):

As you noted, `@types/node` includes only a stub for the `webcrypto` interface. One workaround is to extend the `crypto` module declaration to declare `webcrypto.subtle` as `SubtleCrypto` from the DOM type definitions:

```
// src/types/index.d.ts

declare module "crypto" {
  namespace webcrypto {
    const subtle: SubtleCrypto;
  }
}
```

This allows writing a module like:

```
// src/digest.ts:

import * as crypto from "crypto";

// subtle has type SubtleCrypto, from the DOM type definitions
const { subtle } = crypto.webcrypto;

// Generate a cryptographic digest of the given message
export async function digest(message?: string, algorithm = "SHA-512") {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const data = encoder.encode(message);
  const hash = await subtle.digest(algorithm, data);
  return hash;
}
```

To use `SubtleCrypto`, the project must enable the DOM type definitions by adding `dom` to the `lib` array in `tsconfig.json`. For example, with the following packages installed:

```sh
$ npm install -D typescript@4.6 @types/node@17 @tsconfig/node17
```

and a `tsconfig.json` containing:

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node17/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules"]
}
```

you can write an entrypoint that calls `digest` and prints the result:

```
// src/index.ts

import { digest } from "./digest";

const message = "Hello, World!";

(async () => {
  const digestBuffer = await digest(message);
  console.log(Buffer.from(new Uint8Array(digestBuffer)).toString("hex"));
})();
```

This builds and runs, like:

```sh
$ npx tsc && node dist/index.js
374d794a95cdcfd8b35993185fef9ba368f160d8daf432d08ba9f1ed1e5abe6cc69291e0fa2fe0006a52570ef18c19def4e617c33ce52ef0a6e5fbe318cb0387
```